# I want to upgrade a project build in hibernate 4 to hibernate 5 what all modification or changes to be included for the successful upgrade

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a project already deployed in server which uses spring and hibernate 4.I have to upgrade hibernate 4 to hibernate 5.what all modifications to be made in project pom.xml configurations for the successful upgrade..?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just change the hibernate version in pom.xml file.

```
<hibernate.version>***</hibernate.version> // Replace *** with version.
```

**Example:**

```
<hibernate.version>5.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Do check the **Hibernate Migration Guide** also:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc